# Fixed position div getting hidden for the smaller screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-position

[MY CODE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ArhDz)

I have created a basic structure of my html using bootstrap.

My issue is when the height of drop down in larger than screen 
bottom part of drop down gets hidden as the header is set using `position: fixed`.

I have last option to add scroll to the drop down if height is greater than screen.

I wants the drop down to be scroll when it is larger than the screen.
As the header is `position: fixed` I am not able to scroll the drop down.

Is there any way out of this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing like [this](http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/oyGFE)

What I did is on window scroll calculated the difference between the height of the screen and the drop down.

And moved the drop down using that difference.

Here is the code for it.

jQuery

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var pageHeight = $(window).height() - $('.navbar').height();
  if ($(window).height() < $('.dropdown-menu').height() &&  $('.dropdown-menu').height() > pageHeight && $('#dropDownBtn').hasClass('activeBtn')){
    var scrollMove = $('.dropdown-menu').height() - pageHeight;
    $('.dropdown-menu ').css('marginTop',-scrollMove);
  }
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (st < lastScrollTop){
            $('.dropdown-menu').css('marginTop','0');
        }
        lastScrollTop = st;
})
```

Comment: oops!!! I did not consider that scenario, will need to add one more condition for that. Thanks for bringing that in notice. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is to move your drop-down outside of your fixed element:

working [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JAmfE)

### js click

```
$('#dropDownBtn').click(function(){
    var $t = $(this), $d = $('.dropdown-menu');
    $d.css({top: $t.offset().top+$t.height()+10, left: $t.offset().left-($d.outerWidth(true)-$d.outerWidth(true))});
    $d.slideToggle();
  })
```

You will have to figure out though how to deal with the scrollbar appear/disappear with the pixel jump.. one way to do this maybe is leave body { overflow-y:scroll}, so the scrollbar always appear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would not prefer to change the HTML. Hence I would like to use the solution given by Tushar